# Ionic on Android: Redirect to http://localhost/

Tags: android, redirect, ionic3, single-sign-on, connection-refused

**The Problem:**
The IONIC-Android application refuses a redirect to http://localhost/ sent from an SSO-site.

And crashes with the following error:

[image: Connection Refused]

**The Environment:**

- Ionic 3 Angular
- Android 9.x

Ionic Info:

```
Ionic:                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                       
  ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0                    
  Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2                                                                                
  @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3                                                                                              
                                                                                                                       
Cordova:                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                       
  cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)                                                                       
  Cordova Platforms     : android 8.1.0                                                                                   
  Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 10 other plugins) 
                                                                                                                       
System:                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                       
  Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1                                     
  NodeJS            : v10.16.0                                                         
  npm               : 6.10.0                                                                                              
  OS                : Windows 10
```

**What I do:**
Clicking on a specific button links you to an SSO-AUthority site (directly inside the app)
Here the user authorizes itself with its SSO-Credentials. On success the site redirects back
to it's calling origin, which is in my case the app, so http://localhost/#access_token=...
This leads the application to crash with the shown error.

I've tried updating several plugins like the web view and the in app browser with no change.

**What can I do?:**
I am not sure whether I am doing this right anyway, or if there is a much better way. I tried to get something better than this error message, but there is no detailed error message or any further error when I look at this in Chrome's device debugging mode.

I searched my ass off on this topic, but so far found nothing that helped me in any way. I always end up with the exact same error.

Comment: Are you using the dot net in the back-end? Testing in the device? try http://localhost:8100/#access_token=

Comment: Not 100% sure if i did understand you correctly.
I tried to force the app to open with port 8100 and also get the connection refused.
Seems like anything other than just **http://localhost/** is resulting in a crash.

Comment: Bodo, did you get past this?